# Can't open local .geojson files inside Vue Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, geojson, vue-cli

I am trying to load static .geojson files inside my VueJS project. Simple .json files are working, but .geojson files gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}
    at eval (address.geojson:1)
    at Object../src/venue/amenity.geojson (app.js:1418)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Prodmap.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:13)
```

and so on..
Of course I can switch all files to .json, but this could only be a temporary workaround.

```
import Address from '@/venue/address.json'; // works
import Address from '@/venue/address.geojson'; // gives me the error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue CLI loads JSON natively, but I'm not sure how that can be configured for a different extension.  Here's another option:

Install *json-loader*:

```
npm install json-loader
```

Configure *json-loader* in *vue.config.js* in your project root (create the file if necessary):

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.geojson$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```