# Can i import a variable from a geojson file with Vue 3 and Vite?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3, geojson

I want to import a variable from a geojson file for my vue 3 project but when i do that :
`import line from '@static/line.geojson'`
my page becomes totally empty as if Vue no longer works.

When i use `import line from '@static/line.json'` it works, but I need a geojson file for the rest of my code, so I don't want to have 2 same files with 2 different extensions.

When i check my console, it's say :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at line.geojson?import:2:10)

But I'm pretty sure there's no error in my file because I'm using it in a vue 2 project and it works.

Do you know what i have to do in order to use just one file line.geojson ?
I think maybe there is a pluging to install but i don't know which one.

this is my file line.geojson

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  2.373307391426136,
                  51.02186641516233
               ],
               [
                  2.373339257074004,
                  51.02183268101012
               ],
             // there are others points
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "libelle":"Exploit\u00e9e",
            "geo_point_2d":[
               51.0366532348,
               2.41012862333
            ],
            "mnemo":"EXPLOITE",
            "rg_troncon":1,
            "pk_fin_r":"311+500",
            "pk_debut_r":"304+226",
            "code_ligne":"300000"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Ymasuu. Whenever you encounter this kind of issue, please check your console. It helps you to debug the issue, and you can also provide in your question the information the console gives you.

Comment: You're right i'll edit my first post

Comment: similar issue as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065631/cant-open-local-geojson-files-inside-vue-project

Comment: i use vue 3 with Vite instead of Webpack and json-loader need Webpack if I understand correctly

Answer (score 0):

solution1: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/2d9008e81d0d835e10437a959fac12529f7823e1/packages/vite/rollup.config.ts#L138 vite internally use @rollup/plugin-json to resolve json file.  you can install the plugin and add your options to support the geojson file. maybe the `include` params is what you want https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/json/README.md

(recommended)solution2:

```js
import j from "@/assets/a.geojson?raw";
console.log(JSON.parse(j));
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand everything. I installed @rollup/plugin-json as a dev dependencie (i don't now if it's a bad idea) but now what i have to do ? 
I create rollup.config.js and i put this : 

```js 
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'output',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [json()]
};``` 
But now i don't what params i have to include to use a geojson file.

If i import line like this : `ìmport line from "@static/line.geojson"`, i can't use the datas in my file

Comment: you can try the workaround code. if you want to install the plugin , you need config it in vite.config.js and let plugin to resolve the geojson file